# Characteristic Function of $Y=X+c$

Tags: probability-theory

The sort of problem that I'm working on is actually related to the following previous post:

[Bernoulli Distribution with support different from $\{0,1\}$](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/133200/bernoulli-distribution)

And if $X$ is Rademacher distributed then how do I compute the characteristic for $Y=X+c :(c\ge 0 $ $constant)$

I have the following:
$φ_Y=φ_{X+c}=\cos(t)*\mathbb{E}[e^{itc}]$

I just get the feeling like this is "messy" and should some more elegant/useful representation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Since $c$ is constant, $\mathbb E(\mathrm e^{\mathrm itc})=\mathrm e^{\mathrm itc}$. (And please replace $\varphi_Y$ and $\varphi_{X+c}$ by $\varphi_Y(t)$ and $\varphi_{X+c}(t)$.)